# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install a s/w and run it on cygwin.

1) I unzipped on cygwin using tar -zvxf ABC.tar.gz

2) I copied the execution file ABC.x and copied it to Test folder where there is an input file example.

4) I entered ./ABC.x < input.dat but I received the following error:
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

Can someone please help me? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `file  ABC.x` ?

Comment: ABC.x: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=502fc35f7eddcdcd6a1cb1812cd135707f616812, not stripped

Comment: Sorry, I typed too soon! I just edited my previous answer.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/1177199/what-kinds-of-programs-can-i-run-in-cygwin/1177225#1177225